# Are the NBA champions called World champions? Why is that?

Tags: basketball, terminology, nba

When an NBA team wins the championship, they are called world champions. How did that come about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because NBA is probaly the most important national basketball championship in the world.

Even [Dream Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_United_States_men%27s_Olympic_basketball_team) Olympic performances in world vision helped the thought that the NBA tournament was at a higher level than any other world championships.

[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/sport/blog/2008/nov/18/american-sports-nfl-nba-mlb) has analyzed this issue and emphasized the non-validity of this appellative.

**However, any of this elements does not justify the "World Champions" title.**

Comment: Frankly, that Guardian article is codswallop. The difference in standard between the NBA and even say the Euroleague is huge.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I agree with you, but the focus is that there is no tournament that include other teams outside US/Canada in Nba so is not correct to call the NBA winner also World Camphions. NBA is a national championship

Answer (score 14):

Like it or not, American sports has a history of calling the winner of each of its major professional sports each year "World Champions."  This tradition goes back to the [1884 World Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1884_World_Series).  Besides the NBA and Major League Baseball, the NFL also calls their Super Bowl winning team "World Champions."  It is a little bit of a joke, but also signifies that we American sports fans think of our sports as the best in the world.

Comment: @BenMiller I agree that American sports fans think that they are the best but their thinking is not enough to justify this title at the official level

Comment: Think it's only the MLS and NHL that don't, probably because the level of the international field is way closer than in the NBA, NFL or MLB. (Meaning that if a team from NA was to play against a team from let's say europe, it would not be just straight a stomp by the NA team)

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple premise.  The best players in the entire world (including the best international players) play in the NBA.  Therefore, champions = "world champions", aka winners at the highest level of basketball competition.